# Close all threads, except the main

Tags: c, linux, unix, pthreads

Is there a way to close all created threads if I don't have a list of their identifiers?
It is assumed that I only need the main thread, and the rest can be closed.

Comment: its not clear. can you tell us more and show the code? what you have in main() ?

Comment: Simply don't design a program where nobody knows how many threads there are or nobody is in charge of notifying them to shut down.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually a good idea to have threads in charge of their *own* lifetime, periodically checking for some event indicating they should shut down. This usually make the architecture of your code much easier to understand.

What I'm talking about is along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
def main():
    # Start up all threads.

    synchronised runFlag = true
    for count = 1 to 10:
        start thread threadFn, receiving id[count]
    sleep for a bit

    # Tell them all to exit, then wait.

    synchronised runFlag = false
    for count = 1 to 10:
        wait for thread id[count] to exit
     exit program

def threadFn():
    initialise

    # Thread will do its stuff until told to stop.

    while synchronised runFlag:
        do something relatively quick

    exit thread
```

The periodic checking is a balance between efficiency of the thread loop and the amount of time you may have to wait for the thread to exit.

And, yes, I'm aware that pseudo-code uses identifiers (that you specifically stated you didn't have), but that's just one *example* of how to effect shutdown. You could equally, for example:

- maintain a (synchronised) thread count incremented as a thread starts and decremented when it stops, then wait for it to reach zero;
- have threads continue to run while a synchronised counter hasn't changed from the value it was when the thread started (you could just increment the counter in `main` then freely create a new batch of threads, knowing that the old ones would eventually disappear since the counter is different).
- do one of a half dozen other things, depending on your needs :-)

This "lifetime handled by thread" approach is often the simplest way to achieve things since the thread is *fully* in control of when things happen to it. The one thing you *don't* want is a thread being violently killed from outside while it holds a resource lock of some sort.

Some threading implementations have ways to handle that with, for example, cancellability points, so you can cancel a thread from outside and it will die at such time it allows itself to. But, in my experience, that just complicates things.

In any case, `pthread_cancel` requires a thread ID so is unsuitable based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to close all created threads if I don't have a list of their identifiers?*

No, with POSIX threads there is not.

> *It is assumed that I only need the main thread, and the rest can be closed.*

What you *could* do is have `main()` call `fork()` and let the calling `main()` (the parent) `return`, which will end the parent process along with **all** its thread.

The `fork()`ed off child process would live on as a copy of the original parent process' `main()` but without any other threads.

If going this route be aware, that the threads of the process going down might very well run into undefined behaviour, so that strange things might happen including messy left-overs.

All in all a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to close all created threads if I don't have a list of their identifiers? It is assumed that I only need the main thread, and the rest can be closed.

Technically, you can `fork` your process and terminate the parent. Only the thread calling `fork` exists in the new child process. However, the mutexes locked by other threads remain locked and this is why `fork`ing a multi-threaded process without immediately calling `exec` may be unwise.